# Hacer subplots en Python de imágenes representados en una misma ventana de Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

[image: Represen]

Hola verán me he encontrado con un problema al cual desconozco cómo darle solución. Como ven en la imagen, lo de la izquierda es el frame de Tkinter, el cual si pulso un botón, entonces se crea una figura de Matplotlib para representar lo de la derecha.

El código para implementar esto es el siguiente:

```
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    plt.imshow(np.asarray(ima))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('Imagen original')
    plt.subplot(2,2,3)
    plt.imshow(ima_defecto)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('Simulación de '+defecto)
    plt.subplot(2,2,2)
    plt.imshow(ima_recolored)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('Imagen recoloreada')
    plt.subplot(2,2,4)
    plt.imshow(process.process_image(ima_recolored,defecto, opcion))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('Simulación del recoloreado')
    plt.show()
```

Lo que busco es una **representación** idéntica de **subplots** de Matlplotlib pero **en Tkinter.** ¿Alguna idea de cómo conseguir esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el módulo de matplotlib `FigureCanvasTkAgg` (para eso también tienes que meter tu plot a una `Figure`)

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

Creas la UI en tkinter normalmente:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
```

Luego hacemos lo mismo que hace tu código, pero adaptado al `Figure`:

```
fig = Figure()
a = fig.add_subplot(221)
a.imshow(ima)
a.axis("off")
a.set_title("Imagen original")
b = fig.add_subplot(223)
b.set_title("Simulación de "+defecto)
b.axis("off")
b.imshow(ima_defecto)
c = fig.add_subplot(222)
c.axis("off")
c.imshow(ima_recolored)
c.set_title("Imagen recoloreada")
d = fig.add_subplot(224)
d.axis("off")
d.set_title("Simulación del recoloreado")
```

Luego de tener listo el plot que deseamos, usamos el módulo embedder de tkinter, se le pasa la figura (*fig*) y el widget tkinter padre que va a tener (*root*)

```
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
```

Para trabajar con el widget, usas `get_tk_widget()`, por ejemplo se puede usar para insertarlo en la UI con los geometry managers (pack, grid o place)

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Y finalmente activas el mainloop

```
root.mainloop()
```

Lo probé con una imagen de una flor, solo para verificar, y funciona correctamente!

[image: Imagen demostrando el uso de FigureCanvasTkAgg]

La principal diferencia es que te va a salir sin los controles normales de matplotlib, para eso debes importar `NavigationToolbar2Tk` (junto con el `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, son parte del mismo package) y añadirlo a tu GUI.